# wxWidgets generating .a lib files on windows

Tags: c++, mingw, wxwidgets

Hello I am trying to compile wxWidgets on a win7 machine using the MinGW compilers (v 4.7.1) bundled with Code::Blocks. I've tried both 2.8.12 and 3.0.0. In both cases I use the same batch file to compile:

```
mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc SHARED=0 UNICODE=1 BUILD=release MONOLITHIC=1 clean
mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc SHARED=0 UNICODE=1 BUILD=release MONOLITHIC=1
```

The build process ends with no errors, and I'm left with a handful of .a files in the lib subdirectory.

How do I tell it to compile into windows LIBs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.a` or `.lib` extension is not a matter of Windows vs Linux. It's a matter of gcc vs msvc.
Typically, you will find the same thing inside, but if you try to link with it using msvc, you will encounter mangling problems.

More info on: [Convert from MinGW .a to VC++ .lib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9346054/convert-from-mingw-a-to-vc-lib)

Comment: Aha! why didn't I find that info anywhere else? thanks.