# Use MinGW static library (.a) within Visual studio environment

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mingw, static-libraries

I work on a project that generate several static libraries (.a) from MinGW with Scons project files.

And I need to use these libs into an other project that work on C++ Visual Studio 2013.

First I tried to just add MinGW lib to my VS project and obviously it didn't work out.

I read some things about using a ".def" file to switch from ".lib" to ".a" but found nothing about convertion from ".a" to ".lib". But I have no idea how to get this ".def" file.

Does anyone have some clue that what I am trying to realise is possible (use MinGW into VS2013) ? Or even a solution that can help me :)

Mathieu.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert from MinGW .a to VC++ .lib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9346054/convert-from-mingw-a-to-vc-lib)

Comment: ***But I have no idea how to get this ".def" file.*** I am pretty sure you can't get a `.def` file for a static library. Also read the link above which says you likely can't do what you want because of ABI incompatibilities and other incompatibilities unless you are talking about `c` code.

Comment: My advice is get scons to generate Visual Studio project files and compile the library with Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: In C++ tag the question is moot, since C++ ABI is likely incompatible between two compilers. In C tag the question is valid, but I do not know the answer.